# Vs code install tensorflow on Mac M1 mini

Tags: tensorflow, installation, h5py

First I found that if I willing to install tensorflow there is going to install h5py fst.
Actually I don't know the error's means.
my working environment is MAC os:Monterey 12.0.1 M1 chip
IDLE:VS code python version 3.9.9
And there is the error below

```
Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/f1/dg3072vj3kv3xrm6gfqss0nm0000gn/T/tmpeilgwiek
       cwd: /private/var/folders/f1/dg3072vj3kv3xrm6gfqss0nm0000gn/T/pip-install-hc7lie5i/h5py_bcf2a489a242489e8360576c4d779270
  Complete output (70 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py
  .........
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py/tests/data_files
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py/tests/data_files
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build/lib.macosx-11-universal2-3.8/h5py/tests/data_files
  running build_ext
  Building h5py requires pkg-config unless the HDF5 path is explicitly specified
  error: pkg-config probably not installed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: TF on M1 is different - https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a MacBook Pro M1 with Python 3.9.9 and pip 21.3.1. After several attempts, creating a virtual environment as follows solved the problem for me:

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/tensorflow-metal
$ source ~/tensorflow-metal/bin/activate
$ python3 -m pip install -U pip
$ python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos
$ python3 -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

With the versions:
tensorflow-macos        2.7.0,
tensorflow-metal        0.3.0